# play20.welcome method defined in Play Framework 2.1.2

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am new to Play Framework and am looking at a sample application bootstrapped with `play new`. When I start the application in dev mode without making any changes, there is a bunch of welcome text + markup. It looks like this is all getting drawn from `@play20.welcome(message)`. I see the main layout, main.scala.html and the action's template itself, index.scala.html. I don't however see, where all of this additional markup is from when visiting the home page on a new bootstrapped Play 2.1.2 application via `http://localhost:9000`

Where is all of that markup coming from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It comes from the Play distribution itself, you can take a look at the source code: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.2/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/play20/welcome.scala.html

Answer (score 3):

There is a template file called `welcome.scala.html`. You can find it under

```
$YOUR_PLAY_DIR/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/play20/welcome.scala.html
```

Comment: Just where may the play framework be installed when installing it with the Activator? I suspect the source is not always installed, at least not with the "minimal" version of the Activator.